# asp.net solution with two projects; Why is Request.Form broken and how can I make it work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, webforms

I have a VStudio Solution I started in VS 2013.
At that time I included one project, a WebForms project .net 4.5
It worked fine.

Since then I've opened the solution in VStudio 2015.
The current project still works fine.
but I've added a second WebForm project & again .net 4.5.
one big difference is this new projects, although I select WebForm still sets up an MVC site.

In the previous site I can call a page and I get what I expect of Request.forms.

In the new site, even though I've tried to remove everything MVC, Request.Form is always empty.

Why is Request.Form broken and how can I make it work?

Comment: Did you check your code behind base class?

Comment: All project's pages are System.Web.UI.Page w/ System.Web.dll version 4.0.0.0   ... I'm thinking there is something in the way the two project configure IIS, like deep in the metadata.  But I only know how to look as deep as all the tangible digital assets as the files included in the project's

Comment: Are you sure you're posting values back? Inspect the HTTP POST request and see what values you're posting.

Comment: I direct the post to httpbin.org/post and I see the form{} segment all fields and data

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I've gone through so many iterations of test of VS 2015.

The answer is simple.  Microsoft has yet again f'ing broken something.  .Net 4.52 WebForm site or project simple does not work.  You can not using Request.Form in the receiving web page.  It will forever be empty.  The sending page is certainly doing its job.

VS2015 to create a .Net 4 project / site works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You said you removed everything MVC, which IMO means removing dll references but still an MVC project works on Routes and not actual files, creating a WebForms Website instead might be the solution

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to know which references to remove or leave in.  On "create the correct project"  here is what I'm also finding.  Thank you Microsoft.  Using VS2015 to create a Webforms .net 4.5 ~ no matter what you select in the setup wizard ~ it still creates a MVC site/project.    But created with .Net 4 you get what you expect.  And created as .Net 4 Request.Forms actually works.  .... So my problem is either this.   Something tangible in the References (or something else tangible I've not yet discovered) or intangible in the way VS 2015 sets up IIS Express for the newer project.

Answer (score 0):

Request.Form is simply broken.
Request.Param[] replaces it it I guess.
Thank you Microsoft.